# How do I disable committing of offsets in Spring Kafka to store offsets locally?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to use Spring Kafka to process events into a local database and store the offset in the database itself, as described in https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html under "Storing Offsets Outside Kafka".

Spring Kafka (with a KafkaListener) seems to always commit offsets though (and thus requires a group.id), is there a way to disable commits altogether allowing to listen without a group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container property `AckMode.MANUAL` will disable offset commits by the container.

Comment: But won't it expect the listener to callback the acknowledgement (which triggers commit)? And if I don't do that, will there not be a queue of acks that the container is expecting an ack for?

Comment: No; it will not; calling the `acknowledgment.acknowledge()` simply queues the commit for the consumer thread (MANUAL) or commits the offset(s) immediately when called on the consumer thread (MANUAL_IMMEDIATE). If you don't call the ack, nothing more will happeen; there is no queue of pending acks.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Kafka Consumer has a configuration property enable.auto.commit. This can be set to false so that you can implement a commit strategy in your code. Please see the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#committing-offsets

The KafkaListener annotation can have configuration defined directly. Please see the JavaDoc - https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/KafkaListener.html.

Comment: With enable.auto.commit set to false, the container will still commit offsets according to AckMode. Looking at the code, I haven't found any AckMode that completely disables committing of offsets.

Comment: `AckMode.MANUAL` will disable offset commits by the container.